# Search file

Tags: c#, .net

I have to search the filepath from filename into my harddisk.

I was wondering if there is a way to use main Windows 7 search manager (start->edit text with "search programs and file".
Or simply if there is a quick way to find filepath within computer

Can you help me?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to achieve, your description is not very clear. Also, is this a programming question or are you asking for software recommendations?

Comment: Is this, what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808779/make-a-windows-highlight-search-in-c

Comment: It's a programming question. I would have any filepath from filename that I set.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the [Windows Search SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=645300ae-5e7a-4ce7-95f0-49793f8f76e8&displaylang=en).

Edit: Check out the related MSDN [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266517%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Here's some sample code, i've used in my univercity project:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("/some/path");

foreach (FileInfo i in di.GetFiles("filter.text"))
{ 
     // do something
}
```

Here, `/some/path` is path where you want to search files and `filter.text` is filename filter (for example, `*.*` for all files or `*.cpp` for `.cpp` files match. These would match all files or `1.cpp`, `main.cpp` and `Main.Project.cpp`, respectively).